# plt.show() making terminal hang

Tags: python, matplotlib

At the end of the last function I call in one of my programs, I have the following code to plot a simple color plot.

```
plt.figure()
plt.pcolormesh(X,Y,Z)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Afterwords I return to main and my program is complete.  The plot displays as expected, however when I go to close it using the x button in the corner (on ubuntu), my program doesn't end.  It just hangs there with a process running.  How can I correct this?

Comment: A quick and dirty solution might be to try using `plt.draw()` instead of `plt.show()`. `show()` loads all of the interactive tools, where `draw()` should be a simple viewer which may play more nicely with the rest of your program.

Comment: Also, which version of matplotlib are you using? Version 1.0.0 made some changes to `show()` to make it more compatible with what you want to do. [See the docs](http://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html#use-show) for more info.

Comment: Are you using ipython, or some other matplotlib friendly console which handles the GUI threads correctly?

Answer (score 34):

your matplotlib might be running in [non-interactive mode](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-interactive-mode) for some reason.
I am not sure how to prevent that in your local configuration but if you add either this:

```
plt.ion()
```

or this:

```
matplotlib.interactive(True)
```

somewhere at the beginning of your script, it should change the behaviour of your plots.

Answer (score 4):

For interactive mode, You need this at the head of file:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
```

Comment: You should write this code before importing plt as cited in the answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55811545/importerror-cannot-load-backend-tkagg-which-requires-the-tk-interactive-fra

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has citrix installed and is using linux it might be interupting matplotlib, I have no idea why this is but after days of searching uninstalling citrix fixed the problem.