# how to close plot show in ipython matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, ipython

I used ipython and plot a graph and type `plt.show()`. 
This pops up a graph window. But, when I close the window,
the ipython does not go back to prompt and stays non-responding. 
How can I close the graph window properly and go back to ipython ?

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13557260/plt-show-making-terminal-hang?