# ImportError: Cannot load backend 'TkAgg' which requires the 'tk' interactive framework, as 'headless' is currently running

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, google-colaboratory

When I use google colaboratory, I face this problem, I have searched it on stackoverflow, but few answer, could any guy help me to figure it out? THX!

I have tried to reinstall matplotlib in several ways, and install tk-dev, all of them don't work.

```
import matplotlib
import glob


**matplotlib.use('TKAgg')**


import matplotlib.image as mpimg

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
```

There comes out an ImportError like the Title :"ImportError: Cannot load backend 'TkAgg' which requires the 'tk' interactive framework, as 'headless' is currently running"

Answer (score 19):

What solved the problem for me was to **restart** my kernel, import the following **first**:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TKAgg')
```

**Then**,

`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

You probably imported matplotlib with another framework before you tried to change to `TKAgg`. Restart your kernel.

Comment: Is there a way to solve this without restarting the kernel?

Comment: on WSL, python3.8.5, I read "ImportError: Cannot load backend 'TkAgg' which requires the 'tk' interactive framework, as 'headless' is currently running" when following this

Answer (score 13):

I solved the problem by changing `matplotlib.use('TkAgg')` into `matplotlib.use('Agg')`.

Comment: worked in Ubuntu 22.04 in vs code

Answer (score 7):

`matplotlib.use('TKAgg')` gets there too late maybe (?). I had success setting the environment variable instead.

```
export MPLBACKEND=TKAgg
```

Really odd error message. I was also trying this inside a docker container and had to set `DISPLAY` as well. Maybe there are other errors that aren't being reported. Using [`reload(matplotlib)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14763330/1888983) did not help either.

Comment: That made my day! I had a BASH script running a python script and adding this before running the actual py script made it.

Comment: Tried this approach w/o success :( any more ideas?

Comment: @joyzxyqk What did you set DISPLAY to? :0.0?

Comment: @snark For docker I assume I had `export DISPLAY=:0`, same as the host's `$DISPLAY`. I was also mounting `/tmp/.X11-unix` so that would work. I guess an alternative would be X forwarding over an ssh connection to the container.

Answer (score 2):

`pip install matplotlib==2.2.4`
This version is more stable.

Answer (score 1):

I repeat matplotlib.use('TkAgg') again and again to fix the problem. It's weird but work for me!

```
import matplotlib
i = 0
while i < 10:
    i += 1
    try:
        matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
        break
    except:
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, I was running ubuntu with docker on windows and the reason for this error was that **I didn't start VcXsrv Windows X Server**. when I **started X Server**, the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error when trying to use the Matplotlib GUI on Windows 11 WSL you should run the following in the elevated PowerShell:

```
wsl --update
wsl --shutdown
```

After that you can restart WSL and plots should now display correctly.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps

Answer (score -2):

The error message clearly explains that `TkAgg` needs `tkinter` library.

You can fix this error by importing tkinter library ahead of matplotlib, for example:

```
import tkinter
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
```

Comment: It is not required to `import tkinter` explicitly

Comment: I agree with @gies0r , it neither fix the problem nor required to be added explicitly.

Comment: For me, this suggestion worked. (Setup: ssh -X (x forwarding) to another machine, on which I again forward x into a rootless podman container -- where I finally start python).